# Compiles and runs but it's not there

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, package, jframe

I am trying to run my JFrames from a package folder (which works and has been set up correctly). The problem is that it compiles and runs but I can't see anything and I do not know what to fix since there are no errors. I am probably overlooking something very small, but I just can't pinpoint it. This code is my Main class and the first JFrame class I will be using. Any ideas on how to most efficiently implement a JFrame from a package would be much appreciated.

```
import GroupProject.GUI.Package.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;


public class TestGuiApp1
{

    public static void main(String[] Args)
    {
      // Gets screen dimensions to be used to center JFrame
      Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();

      //creates new Main Menu Frame from GUI packages
      new MainMenuFrame();

      //constraints and unlocking/locking features
      //setLocation((d.width/2)-350, (d.height/2)-350);
      //setResizable(false);


    }

}
```

//**Start of JFrame class from package**

```
    package GroupProject.GUI.Package;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.*;

    public class MainMenuFrame extends JFrame
    {
        private JButton guess_word,
                        guess_number,
                        player_stats;
        private JLabel pic_label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Question-Mark-Man.jpg"));

        public MainMenuFrame()
        {     

            try {

                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel()
                {
                    public UIDefaults getDefaults()
                    { 
                        UIDefaults ret = super.getDefaults();
                        ret.put("defaultFont",
                        new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 16));
                        return ret;
                }
                });

            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

            ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
            // Panel Size
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 300));
            // Background Color
            setBackground(new Color(127, 157, 217));
            p1.setBackground(new Color(127, 157, 217));


            // -------------------- Buttons -------------------

            // Guess a word Button
            guess_word = new JButton("Guess a word", new ImageIcon("word game.png"));
            guess_word.setFont(new Font("ariel narrow",Font.BOLD,24));
            guess_word.addActionListener(listener);
            p1.add(guess_word);

            // Guess a number Button
            guess_number = new JButton("Guess a number", new ImageIcon("number game.png"));
            guess_number.setFont(new Font("ariel narrow",Font.BOLD,24));
            guess_number.addActionListener(listener);
            p1.add(guess_number);

            // View player stats button
            player_stats = new JButton("Player Stats", new ImageIcon("stats2.png"));
            player_stats.setFont(new Font("ariel narrow",Font.BOLD,24));
            player_stats.addActionListener(listener);
            p1.add(player_stats);
            // ---------------------------------------------------



            // ============ Layouts using group layout ============
            GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);

            this.setLayout(layout);
             layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(guess_word, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 280,
                          GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(guess_number, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 280,
                          GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(player_stats, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 280,
                          GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(p2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                          GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()));

            layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(p2, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                              GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(guess_word, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60,
                         GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(guess_number, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60,
                          GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(player_stats, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60,
                          GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))

                    .addContainerGap(239, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
            // ===================================================
            p2.add(pic_label);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Error(ex);
            }
        }  


        private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {   
               //need to set values to remember what game the user wants to play
               // before it goes to the SelectPlayerTypeFrame
               if (e.getSource() == guess_word)
                   ;//new MainMenu();

               if (e.getSource() == guess_number)
                   ; // new MainMenu();

               if (e.getSource() == player_stats)
               ;//new MainMenu(); 
            } 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it out the GroupLayout was using the this keyword and needed getContentPane() instead.

Answer (score 4):

Where do you call setVisible(true) on the JFrame?

i.e.,

```
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

or in your case:

```
this.setVisible(true); // this is not necessary but here for clarity
```

Also note that this should be called after all components have been added to the GUI and after calling `pack` (as noted in another answer on this page).

You will want to go through the Java Swing tutorials to understand how to create Swing programs a bit as this knowledge will be extremely useful to you: [Swing Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Also, I strongly advise you not to use NetBeans to generate Swing code for you, at least not at this stage in the game, not until you understand Swing a little bit more. The code generator is great for quick and dirty code creation, but if you don't know the nuts and bolts of Swing, you can often get stuck if you want to create anything more than the most basic GUI. I know this from experience.

Comment: Originally I tried this but, I got a run-time error ... GroupLayout can only be used with one Container at a time

Comment: Which means you are using GroupLayout wrong. Solution: don't use NetBeans generated code. Instead create your own Swing code using the tutorials as a guide. This includes using the easier to use layout managers if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You never set your frame to be visible, and you don't call `pack()` on it to tell it to size to its child components.

```
JFrame frame = new MainMenuFrame();
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Originally I tried this but, I got a run-time error ... GroupLayout can only be used with one Container at a time